# How do I access lvm disk with same VG name as current?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, lvm

I reloaded my PC onto a new disk then put the old disk back in the PC to recover old files. I kept the same PC name. The OS setup routine appears to have used my PC name (`stiffler`) to create the LVM names.

```
[root@stiffler ~]# pvs
  PV         VG          Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg_stiffler lvm2 a-   232.31g    0 
  /dev/sdb2  vg_stiffler lvm2 a-   232.63g    0
```

So the volume group name on both of my disks has the same name! I'm booted to the correct one, but I would like to access the second one. How do I rename the other one so I can gain access to it by a unique name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

disconnect one of the disks and use vgrename

Comment: Yup. Worked - thanks! I had some problems in the past with an LVM situation where vgrename wouldn't work so I guess I discounted the command prematurely. As a side note, I booted to Fedora 14 LIVE and performed the vgrename that way.

Comment: yeah, the previously not working was probably due to not letting you rename VGs in use

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to (or can) disconnect one of the drives, you can list the volume UUID instead of the old name.

Comment: Do you mean "can't".  Also, should this be a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: No it should be a comment. It's a totally different solution.